# Communication between two kernel-mode drivers

Tags: windows, driver, kernel-mode

I have keyboard filter driver installed on my VMWare virtual machine on win 8.1. I'm able to print pressing keys on console by debug print. 
Now i need to move cursor using keyboard arrows. And here is the question, how to tell mouse driver that we want to move cursor? 
Usually, when we want move our cursor, we just move our mouse and it works. It generates interruption and call mouse driver. Is it possible to call samo interruption from my keyboard filter driver?

Comment: If you want to modify what the mouse does (from kernel mode) you would use a mouse filter driver.  (You might be able to combine the mouse and keyboard filter drivers into a single driver if you wanted.  I'm not sure what the consequences of that would be.)

Comment: [This](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=24) might be useful, though I can't personally vouch for its accuracy.